# InAppBillingBridge could not be initialized in react-native-billing

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to do test purchase using react-native-billing library.

But I see that InAppBillingBridge object could not be initialized by this code:

```
'use strict';

import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
var InAppBillingBridge = NativeModules.InAppBillingBridge; // <-- InAppBillingBridge is undefined
```

I have done all steps which is described here:
https://github.com/idehub/react-native-billing

Does anybody know why it may happens?
@cbrevik

UPD: in my function I do like this:

```
const InAppBilling = require("react-native-billing");
    InAppBilling.open()
      .then(() => InAppBilling.purchase('android.test.purchased'))
      .then((details) => {
        console.log("You purchased: ", details)
        return InAppBilling.close()
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: Did you also added this line `const InAppBilling = require("react-native-billing");`  and then tried to do your function calls on the InAppBilling object?

Comment: yes, I did this way